# Getting part of html site in Python

Tags: python

I am making game, some kind of pokemon go but about hacking.
My game have to download position of device but there is a problem.
I found site that displays your latitude and longitude but i can't get it. I maked a script:

```
import urllib.request
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://python.org/')
html = response.read()
print(html)
```

This script makes the site code is assigning to variable called html and printing it.

(site looks like this)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>...</head>
<body style>
<div class="container">
  ::before
  <div class="rows">
    <div class="col-md-4 current-location-detail">
      <table class="table">
        <trbody>
          <tr>
            <td width="30%">Latitude </td>
            <td id="latitude">50.19869</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Longitude </td>
            <td id="longitude">17.17034</td>
          </tr>
```

How can i get longitude and latitude using this code? Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "part of site"? Do you want read the html without completely downloading it? (that's what `urlopen` does) or do you want to extract some data from the page?

Comment: I need latitude

Comment: <td id="latitude">50.19869</td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = urlopen('http://python.org/').read()

# Create a BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
soup.find("div", {"id": "success-story-2"})
```

In the following examples we received the content of and *element* with *id* "success-story-2". You can use [*find()*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) and [*find_all()*](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) to retrieve the parts of the document you wish.

Comment: Where i can download this libraries?

Comment: @PatrykPopowicz  you don't need to explicitly install urllib2...It's already there... but for bs4 you can do  pip install beautifulsoup4